# Kafka operations

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture, software-design

Hi im very new to Kafka operations, all i understand from it is event data is stored in so called topics. These topics are like logs and are written to disk and even duplicated.

What are producers and consumers? Are they essentially just parts of the application like micro services where one producers data and another requests data?

My question is what exactly is the difference between a conventional database and Kafka topics?
Is it just that the data type is different?
In databases, objects are stored and in topics events are stored? They are both written to hard disk?

What problem does Kafka actually solve?
There are some problems with decentralised micro services with dependencies across micro services

How does Kafka solve this problem?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

First off, producers and consumers can be part of the same application. You don't need to have "microservices" to use Kafka.

> one producers data and another requests data?

Yes

> what exactly is the difference between a conventional database and Kafka topics?

Unclear what you consider as a "conventional" database, but Kafka itself has no query capabilities nor any defined record schema. Such features are enabled by external tooling

> They are both written to hard disk?

Not all databases write to disk. Kafka does write to disk

> What problem does Kafka actually solve?

There's [use cases](http://kafka.apache.org/uses) mentioned on the website, but the original goal was log/metric aggregation into a datalake, not intra-service communication.

But if you have point-to-point-to-point dependency chain, you need to ensure all applications in that chain are up, whereas they could instead fail occasionally and pickup from where they stopped reading from a replicated log

Answer (score 1):

Data is stored in so called topics. These topics are like logs and are written to disk and even duplicated.

> Data in Kafka is seen as events. Each event usually represents that something happened. The event is stored in a given topic on a Kafka broker. The topic can be seen as a way to organize data into categories.

What are producers and consumers?

> Producers create events and submit them to Kafka brokers which then store these events in the appropriate topic. Consumers can consume from the aforementioned data, pulling the events that were created by a producer.

My question is what exactly is the difference between a conventional database and Kafka topics?

> Hard to define conventional. But I suppose no, Kafka is not a conventional database. You will probably often find yourself using other databases with kafka. Kafka is primarilly suited for capturing real-time events, storing them in order to direct them elsewhere in real-time (historical retrieval is also possible).

What problem does Kafka actually solve?

> Handling anything that requires event streaming. It does so durably and provides a large amount of guarantees and flexibility in handling large amounts of data.

In conclusion: I would suggest you start by going through the first part of the documentation found at [Kafka Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#introduction).
If you really want to dive in then you can also find a book titled Kafka: The definitive edition.